# mysql update a table from another 1 to 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is product and one is product_data

The product is master table and product_data is detail table but with 1 to 1 relationship on id column

I have some data in product_data which I want to update in product table

This is the query I use:

```
update product p 
       inner join product_data pp on p.catid=5 and p.id = pp.id
  set p.minp = pp.minp, p.maxp = pp.maxp, p.stores = pp.stores
```

It works fine, but when there are millions of records... it goes very slow and takes a lot of time

Is there some more optimized way to achieve this...?

I can use php code as well to optimize it, so the method does not necessarily have to be mysql specific.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's a 1 to 1 relationship, why not just put it all in the same table?

Comment: Actually the other table product_data is a temporary table that is created and filled with data by a background job. The purpose is that the actual live data in product table does not get effected, until the new data is ready, and when it is ready, we copy it to the live data using some optimized method. – Imran Ahmed 15 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the table by using a join should already be the fastest way to update your data.

Make sure you have these indexes

- `product_data(id)`
- `product(catid, id)`

You can get it even a bit faster by adding a covering index:

- `product_data(id, minp, maxp, stores)`

Comment: The product_data table does not have any other fields than id, minp, maxp and stores... is it wise to create in index on all fields?

Comment: Well, it would speed up your query, because the table itself would no longer be accessed. So this is good. The cons are that write access to the product_data table is a bit slower then and you need a bit more disk memory for the index. No big cons in my opinion, so if the speed of the update statement is an issue then create the index.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely violating normalization by copying values in the 1:1 relationship between tables.    Leave the records in place in the product data file and use a VIEW.

Comment: Actually the other table product_data is a temporary table that is created and filled with data by a background job. The purpose is that the actual live data in `product` table does not get effected, until the new data is ready, and when it is ready, we copy it to the live data using some optimized method.